# How to combine progress notifications

Tags: android

I am trying to combine multiple progress notifications into one notification. Exactly how Android's Download Manager does it. If you download multiple files from chrome, it appears as one notification while downloading. How do i do this? I have my code below but it displays each download as a separate notification.

Main

```
mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) mActivity.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) createNotificationChannel();
    mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mActivity, "FileUpload")
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_upload)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mActivity, R.color.colorNotification))
            .setContentTitle(new File(mFilePath).getName())
            .setContentText(mActivity.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setGroup(NOTIFICATION_GROUP)
            .setProgress(0, 0, true);

    mNotifyManager.notify(2312, mBuilder.build());
```

OnProgress

```
  @Override
  public void onProgress(String filePath, double progress, long uploadedBytes, long totalBytes) {
    mBuilder.setProgress(100, (int) (progress * 100), false);
    mNotifyManager.notify(2312, mBuilder.build());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

From [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/managing.html):

> To set up a notification so it can be updated, issue it with a
>   notification ID by calling NotificationManager.notify(ID,
>   notification). To update this notification once you've issued it,
>   update or create a NotificationCompat.Builder object, build a
>   Notification object from it, and issue the Notification with the same
>   ID you used previously.

To group notifications, try the following.
Create a group notification (`KEY_NOTIFICATION_GROUP` is a String key for the group):

```
Notification groupNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
       .setGroup(KEY_NOTIFICATION_GROUP)
       .setGroupSummary(true)
       // Customize the notification here.
       .build();
```

Then add notifications to this group like this:

```
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
       .setGroup(KEY_NOTIFICATION_GROUP)
       // Customize the notification here.
       .build();
```

[Source](https://willowtreeapps.com/ideas/mobile-notifications-part-2-some-useful-android-notifications)

Note that in this case notifications must have different IDs.

Comment: this does not add to the notification like DownloadManager does it. this will just make the new download replace the original.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Do you create a summary notification (with `.setGroupSummary(true)`)? What api level are you targetting?